# React - how to pass parameter from child to parent in callback function (onClick)

Tags: reactjs, callback

I want to add parameter to my callback function:

`parent(here call callback function with additional parameter passed from child) <- child (here add parameter) <- child`

parent:

```
const forwardToOrder = (TService, currentNote, orderRefNumber) => {
console.log(orderRefNumber) // IS UNDEFINED!!!
}


return (
 <DetailsSection>
                            <ReferenceNumberDetails
                                currentNote={currentNote}
                                forwardToOrder={() => forwardToOrder(TService, currentNote)}
                                labels={labels}
                            />
```

Child:

```
function ReferenceNumberDetails({ labels, currentNote, forwardToOrder }) {
    if (anyNumberExists(currentNote)) {
        return (
            <NumbersWrapper>
                <OrderNumber
//HERE I WANT TO PASS SOME PARAMETER TO BE WRITTEN BY PARENT
                    forwardToOrder={() => forwardToOrder(currentNote?.freight_order?.order_reference_number)}
                    labels={labels}
                    orderReferenceNumber={currentNote?.freight_order?.order_reference_number}
                />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just update like this:

```
forwardToOrder={(orderRefNumber) => forwardToOrder(TService, currentNote, orderRefNumber)}
```